# WCF 3x slower with custom ApplicationPool Identity

Tags: c#, wcf, performance, iis-7

I've hosted a WCF app in IIS 7.5 with HTTPS, TCP and Named pipes bindings.

Currently working on a new version of the webservice, trying to get performance improvements, I'm testing it with client (VS console client) and server (IIS hosted) on the same server when I discover something strange:
When doing tests of 100-1000 calls to a method returning a simple string, a builtin account outperforms a custom ApplicatiolPool identity, a domain user, with about 3x the speed.

I need the AppPool identity to be an domain admin because of the things the service is required to do.

Anyone that can shed some light on this?

Comment: Possibly related to IIS loading user profiles? A builtin account presumably won't have a roaming profile to load, where a domain account might.

Though is it possible to design the service to impersonate its caller (who might be a domain admin) rather than having to run as domain admin all the time?

Comment: We tested with loading user profiles true/false, but didn't experience any notable performance difference. Impersonation is a possibility, but we'd like to find the solution to this instead of circumventing it with changes to app logic. Will test it out though!

Comment: I think your best option could be trying to profile the service execution and compare the results across both accounts to narrow it down. I'm afraid I haven't done this before, so can't recommend a good way to go about it.

Comment: Right you are. See my answer below for what it showed. Wireshark wasn't of much help, but process monitor was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I have found the "problem", even though I can't quite understand it.

As I mentioned I used a VS console client, i.e. debugged in visual studio. After doing some analyzing with process monitor, running both with and without builtin AppPool user, I saw visual studio doing something funky.
When running the AppPool under a domain-admin, VS spawned an additional .vshost.exe process under a different user (couldn't see due to seeing only SID that I didn't bother hunting down) that shot to the roof with network load.

I built the console-project and ran the executable outside of VS, and behold, no noticeable difference between AppPool-users and many times faster than in VS.
No idea *why* this is.

My conclusion is "When in doubt, run Process Monitor!" and that I shouldn't have relied on the visual studio debugger so heavily for performance testing.

Comment: Huh! Weird. I'm curious about what the SID resolves to now :)